# Unable to edit forms in IBM Forms Designer

Tags: forms, designer, lotus

I've created a form in the Forms Designer and saved it. I tried making some modifications to it later, specifically deleting input fields and adding new drop down lists. It won't delete input fields and new drop down lists can't be repositioned.
When trying to delete the program either does nothing or gives me the following error:

**"Delete" did not complete normally.  Please see the log for more information.
com.ibm.form.designer.model.xforms.model.impl.BindImpl incompatible with com.ibm.form.designer.model.xforms80.model.Bind80**

Tried looking up the error but so far no solution. I've tried opening the .xfdl file as xml and edit it manually, it worked ok but now when I re-open the file in the Designer all the fields freeze up as they do with the drop down lists.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to fix the deleting bug from the Forms Designer itself. The best I could come up with is:

- opening the .xdfl file in a text editor and deleting the  tag for the particular field you want to delete
- re-open the file in the Designer and the element can be deletable now
- or if that doesn't work, find and delete any entry related to the element in the text editor and re-open in the Designer.

For the freezing page elements: close the file and restart IBM/Lotus Forms.